# Producer and multiple Consumer problem in Redis

Tags: redis, producer-consumer

I am new to redis. `I write a Script which get keys of constant pattern from redis server and then process them`. But, `The problem is that Script is running multiple times at certain instant of time. Such that same keys are processed multiple times`.

If I delete all those keys after getting them, that will also not work because it might be possible two same scripts get keys at same time and processed them. That will also leads to the same problem of processing same keys multiple times which causes redundancy.

for example
keys are like this:

```
record_user-12
record_user-13
record_user-14
record_user-15
record_user-16
record_user-17
record_user-18
record_user-19
```

Constant pattern = "record*"

Let there are two scripts of same code S1 and S2. S1 start running at t=0 time and S2 start running also at t=0. As pattern is same for every script, so both script get get same keys and processed them which causes redundancy as I don't want to process same key multiple time.

Please help me out

Comment: Why not "divide and conquer", e.g, adjust the pattern for each script instance? If you have two scripts reading keys have them read from different keys (for example, S1 reads odd numbered keys and S2 even numbered keys).

Comment: @nitrin0  I think, you didn't get it. there are many copies of same script and can run any number of script at same time. So we are not sure that two scripts are running or three scripts are running or n scripts are running.

Comment: Well, if that's the case perhaps you could leverage [transactions](https://redis.io/topics/transactions) to ensure only one instance/client is handling a key at a given time. I would specifically look in the [check and set section](https://redis.io/topics/transactions#optimistic-locking-using-check-and-set) of the documentation. With this approach you can essentially guarantee (more or less) atomic operations (update, delete, ...) to a key in a multiple client scenario. It will require additional development though...